# NVIDIA Driver Installation Issue (Not able to Install latest version) GTX 1060 Zotac

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, games

So, whenever i tried to install NVIDIA driver through software and updates application, I used to get blank screen while booting through normal mode.

latest driver for NVIDIA is 418 so far, but in the update menu it just shows up driver version 390.

My questions:

How do i get rid of blank screen while booting?.

Is there any other reliable source to install NVIDIA driver with latest updates?.

Is that okay to run GPU without native it`s driver configuration?.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem recently. The basic problem was that Linux switches over from it's plain graphics drivers to the Nvidia graphics drivers at some point. If the Nvidia drivers are a little dodgy then you get the blank screen and you are not able to fix the drivers because uhm .. the screen is blank.

Luckily you can tell the kernel to not switch over to Nvidia by adding the 'nomodeset' parameter at boot time.  If you are using grub then the line looks like:

```
linux /boot/vmlinux/blah/blah ro quiet splash $vt_handoff_
```

In my case it worked best to delete the 'quiet' and 'splash' and to replace them with 'nomodeset'.

For my GTX1050 the 390 drivers actually worked the best, so try them before you go for the newer versions.

(More details on how to edit boot parameters [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters)).

Mtfbwy!